# jQuery POST doesn't work with form data submission

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, servlets

Below is the code:

```
<form id='schema_update' name="input">
Schema:<br>
<input id = 'schema_value' type="text" name="schema">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And the jQuery code is:

```
$( "#schema_update" ).submit(function( event ) {
            String value = $("#schema_value").val();
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "Servlet",
            data : {
                'mode' : 'Update',
                'attribute' : 'schema',
                'value' : value,
            },
            success : function(data) {
                $("#schema").css("color","red");
                $("#schema").html(data);
            }
        });
});
```

When I input some text and click the Submit button for the form. The POST method is not been called. Why?

Comment: what is schema_value ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the schema_value. Updated it & still doesn't work

Comment: you used schema id in success funtion, there is no schema id in html

Comment: also make sure you are entering correct url address

Comment: Hi I've changed these things. Still doesn't work.

Comment: `success : function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }`  check if this is executed or not

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the method for the form as POST or it will default to GET.

```
 <form id='schema_update' name="input" method="POST">
```

You also have to set the action of your form unless you want it sending the data back to the same page.

```
 <form id='schema_update' name="input" action="Servlet" method="POST">
```

Edit: I thought the question was why it works using Ajax but doesn't with regular HTML form, sorry. Anyway, this might not fix your jQuery problem but it will make the form work for when Javascript is off on the client's browser.

To get the AJAX to work, try this:

```
<form id='schema_update' name="input" action="Servlet" method="POST" onSubmit='return ajaxSubmit();'>
```

With the function ajaxSubmit defined like:

```
 function ajaxSubmit()
 {
         var value = $("#schema_value").val();
         alert('calling ajax');
         $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url : "Servlet",
             data : {
                 'mode' : 'Update',
                 'attribute' : 'schema',
                 'value' : value,
             },
             success : function(data)
             {
                alert('success from ajax');
                 $("#schema").css("color","red");
                 $("#schema").html(data);
             }
         });
         return false;
 }
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please explain your issue.  Because I'm pretty sure its just that you're trigger happy.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.